# how to get the list of values using list<> and session in asp.net mvc2

Tags: list, session, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi I have a list of values contains different types of prices for the plans..

```
 <div id="rs360">
     <span class="font18">Rs.360</span> <span class="font20"></span>
 </div>

 <th width="20%" class="bdrL_blue valignT highlight">
 <a href="<%: Url.Action("Payment", "EmployerVas") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn" onclick="return sms_confirm()"/></a>

<div id="rs1000">
   <span class="font18">Rs.1000</span> <span class="font20"></span>
</div>
```

// the same button event...

when i click the button it should take the value of prices 360 ,1000.. then it redirects to the another page. on that page i click some payment options. so it should show which amount i select here like that...

i don't know what is the best way to do this? please give some ideas to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So you want transfer the values 360, 1000... to your payment page?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(double? price)
{
Session("PickedPrice")=price;
}
```

then your button event is call the controller with your value is price, for ex :

```
$.post("Controller/YourActionName",{ price : value_of_your_price });
```

In your payment's page you can use it by using Session("PickedPrice"), when you done, reset Session("PickedPrice").

This is my solution, it's may not the best way and I just newbie but I want to help you. Try!